# Outlook shows only none and full access for calendar with delegated ownership

Tags: exchange, outlook

Using Outlook 2010 and Exchange 2010 (I am unsure of the service pack levels as I write this):

We have users Albert and Beth. Beth wants Albert to be able to give others in the organization access to her calendar. As Exchange Administrator, we accomplish this by giving Albert 'Owner' permission on Beth's calendar folder in the management shell:

```
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -identity Beth:\Calendar -User Albert -AccessRights "Owner"
```

Albert is able to set permissions on Beth's calendar, but Outlook shows only "None" and "Full Access" options for granting Read access to other users.

We expect to see other options like "Free/Busy".

Has anyone seen this before? 
Is there a work-around or fix?